# Excel VBA reverse result of ado query

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get records from a database and fill them into excel.
This is how I get the data and fill it (note: the query is simplified, I can't just `ORDER BY DESC`):

```
Sub FillPersons(ByRef connection As ADODB.connection)
    Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet
    Set recordSet = New ADODB.recordSet
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT TOP 2 Id FROM Persons"

    recordSet.activeconnection = connection 
    recordSet.Open sql

    Dim a As Variant

    If Not recordSet.EOF Then
        a = recordSet.GetRows
        a.Reverse (a)
        Sheet1.Cells(10, 2).Resize(UBound(a, 1) + 1, UBound(a, 2) + 1).Value = a
    End If

    'Sheet1.Range("B10").CopyFromRecordset recordSet

    recordSet.Close
    connection .Close
    Set connection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the result looks like this:

<kbd>B10</kbd><kbd>B11</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>    <kbd>1</kbd>

instead of

<kbd>B10</kbd><kbd>B11</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>    <kbd>2</kbd>

I've tried to reverse `a` but unfortunately I can't get it to work.

Is there a trick to get the correct result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can use reverse in VBA, you could loop the recordset in reverse or the array in reverse, as its only 2 rows not a big task.

Comment: Why can you not use `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short 'helper' function should replace the VB.Net's [Array.Reverse method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx).

```
Function reverseArray(vals As Variant) As Variant
    Dim tmp As Variant, i As Long

    For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1) / 2
        tmp = vals(UBound(vals, 1) - (i - LBound(vals, 1)), 1)
        vals(UBound(vals, 1) - (i - 1), 1) = vals(i, 1)
        vals(i, 1) = tmp
    Next i

    reverseArray = vals

End Function
```

The maths used to determine the opposing element to flip values with should work with both zero-based and one-based arrays.

```
If Not recordSet.EOF Then
    a = recordSet.GetRows
    a = reverseArray(a)
    Sheet1.Cells(10, 2).Resize(UBound(a, 1) + 1, UBound(a, 2) + 1).Value = a
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sub query it and join the results of first and last as 2 rows

like this, my data not yours, sorry

```
SELECT LAST(OriginalQry1.TeammemberID) AS FirstR
FROM (SELECT TOP 2 TM.TeammemberID
FROM tbl_Teammembers AS TM)  AS OriginalQry1
UNION ALL
SELECT First(OriginalQry2.TeammemberID) AS LastR
FROM (SELECT TOP 2 TM.TeammemberID
FROM tbl_Teammembers AS TM)  AS OriginalQry2
```

Then you can just use copy from recordset?